# How to add a tooltip to a dxButton (DevExtreme)?

Tags: user-interface, knockout.js, devexpress, tooltip, devextreme

I would need something like this (knockout):

```
<div class="button" data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Save', tooltip: 'Click here to save!' }"></div>
```

I need a dxTooltip to show up with the given tooltip text.

I wouldn't like to follow this complicated way: [Creating a ko.observable for each tooltip](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTooltip/?version=14_1)

Comment: You could add a normal tooltip, 
<div data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Save' }, attr: { title: 'Click here to save!' }"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use observable content for tooltip...

```
<div data-bind="dxTooltip: { visible: visible, target: target }">
   <div data-bind="text: tooltipContent"></div>
</div>

var vm = {
    tooltipContent: ko.observable()
    //.....
};
```

I've made a sample here http://jsfiddle.net/p3ret0vx/17/